Emulating differential and common mode in ADC
A differential op amp amplifies the difference and rejects the common signal.
Can you create this effect in ADC (2 or more ADC, not timed multiplexed) and firmware/software by using say channel A and B. For example. If you subtract the signal of channel A from the signal of channel B, you will automatically cancel any signal C that is common to both:
A = A_0 + C, B = B_0 + C, B - A = B_0 + C - A_0 - C = B_0 - A_0.
If you dont need any programmable gain amplifier in ADC because the input can be mapped correctly to say the 24 bit ADC 250mV range. Then is the above used?
If yes. How are the accuracies compared to a real op amp? Why doesnt it seem to be common (pun unintended) 

The TI ADS8363 has dual ADCs which can be operated as eight pseudo- or four fully-differential input channels grouped into two pairs for simultaneous signal acquisition. However, from the documentation can't see any reported difference in common-mode rejection for Differential .vs. Pseudo-Differential. Perhaps a search for Pseudo-Differential ADCs will give an answer.

Yes, this can be used.  It can even be done with consecutive acquisitions (single channel ADC), if the error C doesn't change much from sample to sample.  This occurs when the signals are filtered to well below Fs/4: half Nyquist because they're alternating so each channel has half the sample rate, and "well below" so that attenuation at Fs/4 is adequate for reconstruction purposes.
Obviously, with simultaneous sampling, the timing/filtering requirement is much less restrictive, and simply the correlation between channels, and given what timing error exists between them, will suffice.
You would want to run both ADC channels from the same VREF, of course.  If not, they must be calibrated independently, and the independent variance between VREFs will increase the noise floor some amount.
Real ICs can use this method, or true differential inputs as well.  Some ADC architectures are fully differential, so that measuring a difference between input pins is perfectly natural.
Note that, in all cases, the input common mode range must be respected.  Whether because one input gets clipped by input protection (ESD clamp) diodes, or an ADC channel reads a voltage beyond 0 or MAXVAL.  Note that the CM range of some types may be quite narrow (highspeed pipelined ADCs are a prime one to look out for).
You may find this of interest: SAR ADC Input Types | Analog.com

Some comments that gain matching is critical or the CMRR will suffer a lot. Do you have any idea how to test for common mode rejection. Perhaps using signal generator with the one output splitted into 2 and connecting to them inputs of the 2 ADC?

That would indeed be a fine way to test it.

Here is the result. See https://a4.pbase.com/o12/09/7779909/1/174564248.Xh4rj6QC.ch2andch21mvtest.JPG  note the upper waveform is 10uV scale. the one at channel 3 is at 10mV scale. The software bipolar being deducted is Channel 2 and Channel 3. The screen displays the Channel 2 as difference between the original channel 2 and 3 which is outputed from the same signal generator. Why can you still see sine wave after they are deducted. What common mode rejection ratio is the estimate?

You might want to correlate the output with the input to exclude noise, but yeah, that's the idea. This goes beyond the scope of this question, but would be fine in, I see your latest question. If we are done here, please remember to upvote and accept as answer. Cheers!
