Why does my common mode test still have tiny retained sine wave?
I used this equipment the BMA-200 with the AMP01 having a CMRR of 125dB.

I connected the signal generator output to both the In+ and In-. Yet the waveform still have retained sine wave of very small value (needing 50000X gain). Why? won't it be rejected as well?
Is there a way to estimate what CMRR based on seeing retained sine wave?

To show the waveform at V+, i have to disconnect the V-. The output just need gain of 200 to display the original sine wave from signal generator.


I connected the signal generator output to both the In+ and In-. is this the only thing you've done to measure the CMRR? Can you show a schematic instead? I don't think this is a proper method to measure CMRR.

Im not measuring the CMRR. Just seeing if the same output going to In+ and In- of the equipmemt will get the signal cancelled. The picture shows it very clearly. But there is tiny sine wave retained..Why?


What is your expected CMRR in dB.  What is your measured CMRR in dB.  There will always be some feedthrough - CMRR can't equal infinity.  2) When measuring effects in the ppm range such as this, every detail of the test setup matters.  What is the phase shift between the two input signals.  At some level of error, a phase shift between the 2 signals will be amplified - the correct interpretation of that error isn't a lower CMRR than expected.  It can often take a good bit of time and work to isolate and either eliminate or quantify errors from sources other than the CMRR measure.


The expected CMRR is 125. Im not measuring for CMRR. I just want to see how well can the common mode be rejected. The two input signal came from one output of the signal generator..How can phase shift occur? i hav tested other amplifiers, same retained tiny sine wave. for those who did similar tests. didnt u see any retained sine wave?

"I just want to see how well can the common mode be rejected" "Im not measuring for CMRR" -- then you will have to explain in precise detail what you are doing, because the standard means of "seeing" "how well" "common mode" can be "rejected" is the Common Mode Rejection Ratio. If you can provide a precise definition of what you are looking for, and how it differs from the definition of CMRR, that will greatly help us to answer your question.

I was just expecting all the signal to be cancelled producing only a flat output. But I could still detect a tiny sine wave. If you make tests like this. Are  you supposed to see a flat output?  It's not measuring the CMRR in detail. I just want to know if other amplifiers would produce a flat output.


I connected the signal generator output to both the In+ and In-. Yet the waveform still have retained sine wave of very small value (needing 50000X gain). Why? won't it be rejected as well?

Since no amplifier has perfect common mode rejection, there will not be perfect cancellation. You will get some signal at the output, though it may be very small. The ratio between the AC amplitude of this output signal to the AC amplitude of the input signal is the common mode gain.
Note that you are lucky that the amplifier didn't saturate when you applied the same signal to both In+ and In-. All amplifiers have offset voltage. That is, In+ and In- need to be slightly different to make the output 0. That difference is the input offset voltage. If you multiply the input offset voltage by the gain of the amplifier, you get the output offset voltage. For some amplifiers, the open-loop output offset voltage is greater than the voltage swing available in the opamp. In your case, that is apparently not the case.

Im not measuring the CMRR. Just seeing if the same output going to In+ and In- of the [equipment] will get the signal cancelled. The picture shows it very clearly. But there is tiny sine wave retained..Why?

The common mode rejection ratio is the ratio of the common mode gain to the differential mode gain. Your test showed the common mode gain, so to find the common mode rejection ratio, you must also find the differential mode gain. There are a number of ways of doing this. For an open-loop op-amp, you must first bring your input signal down to a level that is sufficiently small that it does not saturate your op-amp. This can be achieved by using a voltage-divider. Then apply this attenuated signal to one input, and hold the other signal at some reference point. A good reference point might be the mid-point between the voltage rails.
Once you have found the common mode rejection ratio, you may want to convert it into decibels (dB). To do so, take the base-10 logarithm of the ratio, and multiply that number by 20.

$20\times log_{10} (2000) \approx 60$. So if a CMRR of 2000 is about 60 dB.

I'm sorry, I wasn't thinking properly. The ratio between your output (with both inputs tied together) and your input is your common mode gain. Your common mode gain divided by your differential mode gain is your common mode rejection ratio. I will edit my answer.

my signal generator has 10uV, 30uV, 5uV, 1mV output..If all wont saturate the output. what must i choose. how do i know im getting the optimum differential mode gain?

Try 10uV, if the amplifier saturates, use a voltage divider, and try smaller signals until the amplifier doesn't saturate.

If I can get it to say 1uV. then the maximum gain is when further gain wont amplify it anymore?

I'm not sure what you mean by maximum gain, or why you want to find it, or what "further gain" means.

remember im measuring for the differential mode gain. so by using 1uV differential input then the differential mode gain is the maximum gain where increasing the gain knob wont increase the gain anymore. Right? you didnt give in instruction about this

I am confused by what you are doing or trying to do. What do you mean by "increasing the gain knob won't increase the gain anymore"? I assume you are viewing the results on an oscilloscope. When I speak of saturating the amplifier, I mean the output is no longer a sine wave, but is clipped. When you say "increasing the gain knob won't increase the gain anymore", are you referring to clipping of the output? If you are clipping the output, you need to turn the gain down. If you are at the minimum gain, and you are still clipping, you need to attenuate the input signal.

oh i think i got what u meant..my amplifier the BMA-200 if you will check at google its close up front panel can make you select gain up to 50000. so ill select it until it wont saturate. thats it

I understood now. Before I was thinking if the maximum gain is reached. There will be no further amplification now I know there is still further amplification, only it will saturate or clip. Last. going back to measuring common mode gain. so it's output amplitude / input amplitude? Since my output amplitude is 2.83uV and input amplitude is 5.84mV. I thought it was input/output = 5.84mv/2.83uV = 2000 gain.or 60dB.  So it must be reversed or 2.83uV/5.84mv = 4.84 x 10^-4 or 0.0000484 gain?

It's output over input. An amplifier with good common mode rejection will have a common mode gain less than one, or in terms of dB, less than 0. 4.84 x 10^-4 is 0.000484. You have too many zeros.

the above is the easy problem. here is the hard one many doesnt seem to know. for example how do you measure differential gain to something that doesnt have any differential gain pls reply in this new subject https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/713911/how-to-measure-differential-gain-of-2-adcs-deducted-in-software-to-get-cmrr it is the main amplifier im really using, not this one. many tnx
