How to measure differential gain of two ADCs deducted in software to get CMRR
I have this product g.USBamp where the 16 channels has bipolar mode by software, such that if you say deduct the independent ADC 2 and ADC 3 (not time multiplexed). You will get both differential output (simply from for example 8-6=2  and even deduct common mode (simply because all differences will be deducted).
The very epxensive $17500 g.USBamp is the clinical standard used by most R&D, universities and even hospitals worldwide. Some say the technique is prone to bad CMRR. Because If you want to have a common mode rejection of, say, 50 dB, the paths need to be gain matched to 0.03 dB. They said that's a lot easier to do on a single small piece of silicon vs two different signal chains with their Rs and Cs, ADC chips etc. or the multiple inputs may have slight variations in scaling going it.
I want to measure the CMRR to see just how bad it is (if it is really bad). CMRR being differential gain divided by common again. I know how to measure the common mode gain, simply by dividing the output amplitude to input amplitude generated by signal generator connected to both the inputs of ADC 2 and ADC 3 (or other bipolar pairs).
How do you compute for differential gain? It has this specs:
https://www.gtec.at/product/gusbamp-research/
sensitivity 85,7 nV / +/- 250 mV
Amplifier type  real DC coupled
16 × ADC    24 Bit (38.4 kHz internal sampling per channel)
It doesn't use any amplifier or use any programmable gain amplifier before the ADC. The signal is mapped directly to the +/- 250mV range ADC such that if you have 10uV signal, It is mapped to the 10uV of the 250mV range. With this info. Is it possible to just compute for the differential gain? How? If not, how do  you measure it? If your input is 10uV, you will also see 10uV in the display, since there is no gain.
And since there is no gain, then differential gain is 0?  and  CMRR = differential gain/common gain = 0? But doesn't make sense for CMRR to be zero. How to do you compute for CMRR here if it uses other formula?

Note, you don't need to physically gain-match channels, you only need to match their gain calibrations. 1e-5 gain calibration accuracy is easily possible, and would give you something like 100-3= 97 dB CMRR

where do you access the gain calibrations? after i correctly measured the CMRR. ill try to calibrate it if i can access it. btw is there any app to know what brand/model is the ADC used so i can access the gain calibrations?

You don't have to do that. The device manufacturer already has. I'm just saying that it's eas for the manufacturer to achieve 100ish CMRR with this arch, because you were doubting if even 50 dB was realistic

Ok. so pls tell me how to measure for differential gain bec i want to measure the CMRR just to check.

Apply the same signal to two channels. Sweep the signal over the full range, and observe the measured difference. You know the difference is zero, so anything measured will be CM-DM conversion gain.

I know how to measure for common mode gain. that is why my thread subject is how to measure differential gain. so how do you measure differential gain only?

The "differential gain" is "1" with a very low difference (some nV/uV probably) for all the channels ... Apply the definition for finding these "differences".

so the normal formula of CMRR doesnt apply? Can someone give an Answer giving more details how to measure it. for example Tobalt mentioned "You know the difference is zero, so anything measured will be CM-DM conversion gain". when asked to elaborate what it even means. he didnt response so someone make an answer giving more clarity to all this tnx

But Antonio answered your request for elaboration. The differential gain (more precisely the DM-to-DM-gain) is very close to 1. It depends on the calibration accuracy used by the device maker. For most intents and purposes, it is 1. To confirm the actual value, you will have a calibration standard that is better than the calibration of the device, which could be hard. The DM-to-DM-gain has nothing to do with CMRR - that would be CM-to-DM-gain.

Hi the BCI2000 software doesnt use the internal DSP of the g.USBamp to deduct the bipolar. Instead it deducts the 2 channels in the outputs via a separate Spatial Filter. Can this introduce any additional output gain match related problem?

Made with microcap v12.
Applying the "definitions" ...
The input impedance of the ADC must be as high as possible, if not ... lower the R2 value.
Corrections may be done if the input impedance is too "low".
So, measure like this. Just varying the input between limits.
Measure vadc1 and vadc2 as a single channel (gain = ~ 1.000..xxx).
And measure these two inputs as "differential" channel.
NB: The resistors don't need to be very high precision (0.1%), but "very" stable.

Here is a more complete setup. R2 can be 100 kOhm or 10 kOhm.
Sw1 and Sw2 are in "opposite" conditions (measuring adc1 OR adc2).
Sw3 and Sw4 wire the internal impedances of adc1 and adc2.
You can then measure adc1, adc2, adc1-adc2, CMRR1 ... adc2, adc1, adc2-adc1, CMRR2.
With all these, you can specify the "errors" of the system.
When Sw1, and Sw2 are in the "same" position, you can measure the same voltage ...
same "content" read in adc module ... if the internal "ways" are the same ...


What simulator did you use? All the ADCs only have one channel connector. Are you treating the channels as resistors? why are the resistors values 1 and 100K? Pls show how you compute it all for the series.  Is the 1 a 1 Ohm or 1 MegaOhm?

Made with microcap v12. Input impedance channels must be only the "same" and "high". 1 Ohm is used by ADC's to measure "differential" voltage or "simple" voltage. 100 kOhm is for applying common voltage (may be lower as 10 kOhm or even 1 kOhm). As there is the same (precision 0.1%) for all channels, they do not really matter. As measurements are done (adc1, adc2, adc1-adc2), you can then specify (I think so) "common mode" and "differential mode" errors (channel by channel) ... and calculate then CMRR.

btw the maximum range of the g.USBamp is only + - 250mV as I mentioned in original question. Anything above it can saturate or clip it! Why is the voltage source 1V? pls take it into account

1V was just a "thought" ... use what is permitted with the board :-) ... So from -250 mV to 250 mV ... Nothing changed. You need to make these measures for all the interval with "some" points.
